# How to properly use refs in React functional components

Tags: reactjs, ref

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) say this:

> **You may not use the ref attribute on function components** because they don’t have instances.

Is this to say that we shouldn't be using refs anymore in React? What is the pattern for accessing the native DOM elements properly in functional react components if not refs? This is so you can pass a ref to a function component, not to a native DOM tag.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that you can use them **in** functional components, but not **on** them:

```
const MyComponent = <div ref={OK} />
const SecondComponent = <MyComponent ref={N/A} />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use document.getElementById() like the old days

Answer (score 0):

**Is this to say that we shouldn't be using refs anymore in React?** No, you can still use ref with functional component.

**What is the pattern for accessing the native DOM elements properly in functional react components if not refs?** [Forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).